# Rework for loop over STL container to use functional techniques

Tags: c++, functional-programming, currying

I have a `std::vector` of pointers `Person` objects, which have a member function `std::string getName() const`. Using STL algorithms I want to count all the `Person` objects in the vector where `getName()` returns "Chad".

The behaviour simply iterating over the loop would be:

```
int num_chads = 0;
for(std::vector<Person *>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
{
    if((*it)->getName() == "Chad")
        ++num_chads;
}
```

I want to rework this so it uses all STL algorithms and functors etc (make it more functional-oriented). This is what I think I need to do:

```
const int num_chads = std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                                    std::bind1st(std::bind2nd(std::equal_to, mem_fun(Person::getName)), "Chad"));
```

As you can probably tell this doesn't work. Firstly, as I understand it, you can't use bind1st/bind2nd on binder1st/binder2nd objects as they are specifically designed to work with `std::binary_functions`. Secondly, and much more importantly, I don't think I am using the correct technique. I *do* want to bind one of the arguments to "Chad", but with the iterator argument I actually just want to transform the iterator value to a string before calling the bound version of `equals_to`.

I think it is possible to do this using Boost, but is it possible using just the core C++03 (i.e. no C++0x lambas!)?

EDIT: Can anyone come up with an example which does not use a user-defined predicate (i.e. just using the tools provided in the std toolkit)?

EDIT: While Matthieu's answer is a textbook answer for how to use functors in STL algorithms, Cubbi's answer came from the approach I was looking for (although Mathieu did answer before I edited the question to make it more specific, so apologies there!).

Comment: Not an answer: I like functional techniques, but I gave up on stl-algorithms for objects.  Lambda's really are the missing link in C++03.  Even with boost.lambda, there are many quirks.  Stl-algorithms works well with primitives, but I rarely use containers of primitives...  Is it worth avoiding loops when they are replaced by bind-constructions?

Comment: Is it normal that `getName()` would return by copy ?

Comment: boost::bind is a lot cleaner than std::bind though, and you can combine boost lambdas in.

Comment: @stefaanv - I think in practical terms I would agree most of the time. If an example this simple came up I would probably just write the loop out.
@Matthieu - I understand where you are coming from, but the example is contrived for the purpose of this question and return by copy vs return by const ref is not something I really thought about (I don't think it changes the framing of the question).

Comment: @Rodion Ingles: not at all, as far as I know, the creation of the temporary will slightly complicate the compiler's job but should not impact the correctness of presented solutions.

Comment: I am trying (and failing) to find a solution to what you are asking for. I hope someone has more success than me, or that someone could explain why it can't be done.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe you couldn't do that because C++98 did not include the required part of STL, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325122/rework-for-loop-over-stl-container-to-use-functional-techniques/5326725#5326725

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since nobody posted the actual boost code yet, C++98 with boost:

```
ptrdiff_t num_chads = std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                      boost::bind(&Person::getName, _1) == "Chad");
```

test run https://ideone.com/PaVJe

As for pure C++, I don't think it's possible without the `compose1` adaptor, present in STL but not in C++ stdlib...

and here it is (using GCC's implementation of STL)

```
ptrdiff_t num_chads = std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                     __gnu_cxx::compose1(
                         std::bind2nd(std::equal_to<std::string>(), "Chad"),
                         std::mem_fun(&Person::getName)));
```

test run: https://ideone.com/EqBS5

EDIT: corrected to account for `Person*`

Comment: Small difference, the OP uses `std::vector<Person*>` which is where all the issues come from. It means you need (apparently) to dereference `Person*` before applying the member function, and there's a possibility it's null (in the general case).

Comment: @Matthieu M done: `s/mem_fun_ref/mem_fun/`m although the possibility of null pointer dereferencing is certainly going to be present with most one-liner solutions. That is, it can be taken care of, but the solution would become unreadable.

Comment: @Matthieu - does the fact that the vector contains `Person *` make a difference (other than the above mentioned null pointer issue)? The only change I can see is that you need to use mem_fun instead of mem_fun_ref which effectively reduces to the difference between .* and ->*

Comment: @Rodion: I hope not :P I think `boost::bind` automatically copes with it.

Answer (score 9):

I have always found lambdas relatively unreadable. I much prefer to write explicit types:

```
struct Named
{
  Named(char const* ref): _ref(ref) {}
  bool operator()(Person* p) const { return p && p->getName() == _ref; }
  char const* _ref;
};

size_t const c = std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), Named("Chad"));
```

Though the definition of `Named` is "out-of-line", a properly chosen name conveys the intention and hides the implementation details. Personally, I consider this a good thing, because then I am not distracting by implementation details or trying to figure out what's going on by reverse engineering the code (as evident as it might be).

Comment: This is a good solution, but personally, I see functors used for this as poor man's lambda's, mainly because of the boiler plate code involved.

Comment: @stefaanv: I agree with the boilerplate, but since we use naming to carry intent, anonymous functions lack this level of explicitness, of course, for such simple functions, one might argue that it's evident... however the arcane syntax of `std::bind*` hides the simplicity.

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution for balancing a more functional approach without currying the STL functors. However I was really looking for something which didn't involve writing your own function objects (I know this wasn't specified in the question). That said, clearly a good example of using a custom predicate in count_if.

Comment: But, can `Named` be declared in the same function in which it is used? Every time I try I get scope errors.

Comment: I think "size_t const c = std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const Person& p){ return p.GetName() == "Chad"; });" is still okay, but it probably quickly gets more complicated.

Comment: @Rob Adams: unfortunately no, I suggest anonymous namespaces. The C++03 standard actually forbids the use of function-locally defined types as template parameters (I think it's an issue of linkage, but you'll need someone more savant than me for a confirmation).

Comment: @stefaanv: True lambdas are quite readable, I agree, however the OP specified that he wanted a C++03 solution, and unfortunately I cannot think of any elegant solution with `bind` (whichever version). I'd really like DeadMG to expand on his answer as to see the syntax he had in mind.

Comment: @Rob - This answer misses out some information for the sake of brevity. Named is a struct, which means that it can only be defined in another class definition or as a struct on its own (this applies to classes as well). You cannot define a class inside a function, which was always one of the biggest problems about using custom functors: they have to be defined away from the point they are being called. This is where lambas come in and make things more appealing by letting you effectively define one function in another.

Comment: The approach is right, but the implementation isn't. Inside the functor you are storing a pointer to a literal, and comparing that pointer with the result of a call to the `getName()` function, which will most probably not be a pointer to the same string literal.

Comment: @David: nope, actually, as per my remark, it returns a `std::string` (by copy).

Answer (score 1):

Use `boost::bind`, it's superior by quite some way to the existing Standard binding mechanisms. `boost::bind` is completely C++03 compatible.

Comment: Can you think of any way of doing it without Boost?

Comment: Or, if not, provide a Boost answer? (Or both! :P)

Comment: @Rodion Ingles: Sure, but it would involve just writing `boost::bind` again yourself, which is rather pointless. As for providing such an answer, well, the documentation is perfectly sufficient for you to do it yourself. It's the job of the answer to help you, not hold your hand.

Comment: Well maybe you have a point about providing a Boost example, but your trite answer about "writing boost::bind again yourself" doesn't serve anyone but you.

Comment: @Rodion Ingles: That's not true at all. `boost::bind` is how it's done. Either you use `boost::bind`, or you roll your own `boost::bind`, but at the end of the day, it's still `boost::bind` under whatever name you give it.